# nsupdate for Windows with GSSAPI

Tags: windows, bind, nsupdate

I'm looking for solution how to use nsupdate from BIND utils with Kerberos in Windows environment. In Linux I have same utils compiled with GSSAPI support, but in Windows I unfortunately don't know how to recompile it. Can you please help me or give some alternative solution to update DNS records from Windows environment using Kerberos.
Big Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for something like dnscmd.exe?

Comment: yes, dnscmd was first way to try, but I cant use dnscmd because it doesn't supports any secure protocols and AD&DNS admins dont accepts any compromices - Kerberos or nothing.

Comment: If you're using Linux, i think this might help you: https://serverfault.com/questions/1131671

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit confusing so I may miss something in my answer. I'm guessing you want to update AD-integrated DNS.

1. **Nsupdate**
   Regarding recompiling nsupdate - where did you get stuck? "I don't know how" is a bit vague.
2. **dnscmd.exe**
   I guarantee that dnscmd authenticates using AD kerberos. You can verify this by running "klist" before and after running a successful dnscmd command (you will see a new service ticket against the relevant DC)
3. **Network settings**
   In the advanced settings on your windows hosts, you can select "Register this connection's addresses in DNS", along with some other relevant options. This can allow you to have hosts update their own dns entry, secured by kerberos. This obviously depends on your setup and won't help with non A/PTR records.
4. **Powershell**
   Haven't verified how kerberos fits, but here's an example command

   Add-DnsServerResourceRecordA -Name "host23" -ZoneName "contoso.com" -IPv4Address "172.18.99.23" -TimeToLive 01:00:00